# What do the existence and parameters of an efficient investment tell you about the value of a risk-free return?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, capm, asset-allocation, learning

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> Consider the following risky investments \begin{matrix}
> \text{name} & \text{expected return} & \text{standard deviation of return} \\
> A & 9\% & 21\% \\
> B & 5\% & 7\% \\
> C & 15\% & 36\% \\
> D & 12\% & 15\%
> \end{matrix} Suppose there is a risk-free return $R$ and you are told that $C$ is efficient. What can you say about the value of $R$?

There are other questions about finding the market portfolio, so I'm guessing something different is intended here, but I can't think what. Could someone give me a pointer? (CAPM assumptions apply.)

Comment: It seems a little trivial but because of risk aversion, R must be less attractive than risky efficient investment C so $R < 15$ percent

Comment: @nbbo2 Thanks, and agreed, but I think the question wants something more substantial (probably with working).

Answer (score 1):

I have given it a bit of a thought and here are my 50 ct:

If C is the only efficient portfolio, then your riskfree return shouldn't be lower than 10 %, otherwise A,B or D are above the line and thus not inefficient anymore.. Given C and D, you can construct a line and check its value at $\sigma=0$, then add a bit on the riskfree return such that D becomes inefficient.

[image]

.. just a thought. Happy to discuss!

Comment: ...and not be above 15%, I'd say.

Comment: Well spotted 

Comment: I follow that train of thought. Yet, geometrically, I truly have a hard time drawing an efficient frontier (without risk free asset) in this example.

Comment: Yes, I was also struggling with it. Perhaps C And D are nearly perfectly positively correlated? The problem doesn't tell us anything about it unfortunately..

Comment: If they were perfectly correlated,  intuitively, I’d assume that we would have to reflect the lower half of the frontier at the corresponding point on the y-axis. Then, asset B would be outside the frontier. Maybe the assets have not been selected sufficiently carefully  ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I think it makes sense only if all assets are perfectly correlated, however, then we have a bunch of other issues here.. In any way this is a weird task